# How to get the particular package from the exception stackTrace in java

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

I want to print only particular package from the exception stackTrace. How to achieve this?

For example, consider the following stacktrace

```
com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: DBPort.findOne failed
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:153)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.testMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:371)

    at com.myapp.foo.MongoConnection.java:10
    at com.myapp.foo.MongoConnection.java:27
```

I want to print only the package "com.myapp.foo" in the stackTrace with linenumber and methodName

Comment: Are you **catching the exception** and wanting to only print a portion of the stacktrace? More information about this is fitting into your application.

Comment: Exceptions provide a getStackTrace-Method. Or you could write your own exception and overwrite the printStackTrace-method. Why do you want to do this anyways?

Comment: yes, I am catching the exception. I also tried with java.lang.stackTraceElement but I don't want to iterate this array from exception.getStackTrace()

Comment: I would go with iterating over the `StackTraceElement` array, or something similar. I've done something similar to this using `printStackTrace(PrintStream s)` and filtering the stream.

Comment: Is there any other way without iterating this StackTraceElement?

Comment: You could always split on new lines and only show the lines containing "com.myapp.foo".

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
try {
  throw new RuntimeException();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
  StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();

  for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stackTrace) {
    String className = stackTraceElement.getClassName();
    int pos = className.lastIndexOf('.');
    String packageName = className.substring(0, pos);
    System.out.println("Package:" + packageName +
        ", method: "+ stackTraceElement.getMethodName() +
        ", line:" + stackTraceElement.getLineNumber());
  }
}
```

You can of course add any custom package filtration you need.